# PYQT5 - How to call another screen using PyQT (MVC)

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

Guys!

I'm working with QTDesigner and PyQT5, I've created two screens using QTDesi. A Login form and a Main form. I'm trying to call the main screen after the login screen. But it didn't work. I've looked up to many tutorials, but non of them, worked for me.

Here's some code:

To call the Login Screen, I've used this class (On Controller):

```
class LoginController(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.txtLogo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('../gui/img/icons/aperam.png'))
        self.action_performed()

    def action_performed(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.valid_login)

    def valid_login(self):
        user = self.txtUser.text()
        password = self.txtPassword.text()
        if model.validate_login(user, password):
            self.close()
            main = HomeScreen()
```

Then, to call the Main Screen, I'm using this:

```
class HomeScreen(Ui_Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(HomeScreen, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Model()
        self.main = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.login_home_screen()

    def login_home_screen(self):
        self.ui.setupUi(self.main)
        self.main.show()
        self.ui.actionNovo.triggered.connect(self.user_screen_show)
        self.main.close()
```

But It didn't work for me. It only shows up a black screen then closes.

The "Start" from the system is this code (Where I call the LoginScreen):

```
cd = LoginController()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    ui = LoginController()
    cd.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Can you help me? I've tried to many tutorials and articles, but both them didn't work. I want to call another form after the login is sucessufuly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various problems with your code.

- `HomeScreen` should inherit from QMainWindow too, not only from `Ui_Model`;
- you should avoid mixing QWidget/uic creation styles;
- you should not call the base class `__init__` if you're also calling `super().__init__` afterwards;
- you create a `HomeScreen` instance (`main`), but then the function returns, which means that that instance will be instantly garbage collected;
- two instances of `LoginController` are being created, but you only need one;
- the home screen is shown and closed afterwards, which doesn't make much sense;
- there is usually no need to create other functions if you just run them once (I'm referring to `action_performed` and `login_home_screen`), especially if they only do small tasks that can be included in the `__init__`;

The simplest solution for your case is to create a custom signal for the login screen, and connect it to the `show` function of the home screen window.

Note that I don't know what `user_screen_show` does; if it's used to show again the login, you should use a similar system to show the dialog again.

```
class LoginController(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    loginSuccessful = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoginController, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.txtLogo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('../gui/img/icons/aperam.png'))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.valid_login)

    def valid_login(self):
        user = self.txtUser.text()
        password = self.txtPassword.text()
        if model.validate_login(user, password):
            # login is valid, emit the signal
            self.loginSuccessful.emit()
            self.hide()


class HomeScreen(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Model):
    newLogin = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(HomeScreen, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.actionNovo.triggered.connect(self.user_screen_show)

    def user_screen_show(self):
        self.newLogin.emit()
        self.hide()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    cd = LoginController()
    cd.show()
    home = HomeScreen()
    cd.loginSuccessful.connect(home.show)
    home.newLogin.connect(cd.show)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hi,  
I've crated the custom signal as you recommend, and It works well. Like you said, I've fixed the 07 bugs into the code. I was pretending to call the main screen inside the login class, to probably the reason he didn't work. 

Now it's working property, I'll use the same way to improve the another screens of the system.

Thank you very much!

Comment: There's nothing wrong in creating a new widget instance inside a class, it's only a matter of class hierarchy and programming logic. It didn't work because of the garbage collection (the object is *local* and, since it has no other reference, it is deleted as soon as the function returned), and it wouldn't have worked anyway due to the `close()` call.